# disk based storage in mysql cluster

Tags: mysql, partitioning, cluster-computing

I have been trying to find out if it is possible to do table
partitioning with disk based tables in MySQL Cluster.  I want to store a
large table on disk, and do range partitioning on the table.    I have a
feeling the answer is no.

Thanks for any info you can offer.

Mike.

Answer (score 2):

Any columns that are not indexed can be stored to disk with MySQL Cluster (since about a year ago or so I think).

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-cluster-disk-data.html

Comment: Weird - why did that deserve a minus-karma?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like only partitioning by key is supported for cluster, whether in memory or on disk:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning-limitations-storage-engines.html

Range partitioning (and Hash, and List) are possible if MySQLD is started with the --new option, so data can be stored on disk, partitioned by range, . Cluster